# laravel query with a model function

Tags: laravel, function, model

I have this function in my model:

```
 public function isFull(){
        $maxMembers=$this->course->type->max_members;
        $countActualMembers=LessonLicenseMember::where('lesson_id',$this->id)->count();
        if( $countActualMembers < $maxMembers) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to use it in a laravel query like this?

```
 public function getOpenLessonsInCourses($licenseMemberId)
    {
        $lessons =Lesson::select ('lessons.id as idLesson','courses.id as id','course_type.description as description'
            ,'lessons.number as number','lessons.date_time as date_time')
            ->status('aperto')
            ->concluded(false)
            ->join('courses','lessons.course_id','courses.id')
            ->join('course_type','courses.course_type_id','course_type.id')
            ->get();
        return $lessons;
    }
```

The purpose is to have the lessons that aren't full, but I don't have a field in my table. 
I know there are scopes but I think they work only with fields in the table...

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing function, the only way I would know to make it work would be to first get all the lessons, then filter that collection to see which are not full, then use whereIn to filter your query in the controller.  It would be something like this.

```
public function getOpenLessonsInCourses($licenseMemberId)
{
    $openLessons = Lesson::all()->filter(function ($lesson, $key) {
        return !$lesson->isFull();
    });

    $lessons = Lesson::whereIn('id', $openLessons->pluck('id')->all())
        ->select ('lessons.id as idLesson','courses.id as id','course_type.description as description'
        ,'lessons.number as number','lessons.date_time as date_time')
        ->status('aperto')
        ->concluded(false)
        ->join('courses','lessons.course_id','courses.id')
        ->join('course_type','courses.course_type_id','course_type.id')
        ->get();
    return $lessons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at conditional clauses:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses

The syntax would look something like:

```
// find your lesson so you can use the isFull method
$lesson = Lesson::find(1);

$lessons = Lesson::select ('lessons.id as idLesson','courses.id as id','course_type.description as description','lessons.number as number','lessons.date_time as date_time')
   ->status('aperto')
   ->concluded(false)
   ->join('courses','lessons.course_id','courses.id')
   ->join('course_type','courses.course_type_id','course_type.id')
   ->when($lesson->isFull(), function ($query, $lesson) {
       // return your query object here
   })
   ->get();

return $lessons;
```